# Node.js and Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, pug

I'm pretty good with javascript but I am fairly new to node.js and jade. I'm attempting to create a basic chat server using socket.io (following a tutorial I found online) but I am having trouble getting it up and running.

To start off i created a basic package.json file that included the following which when run created `node_modules` directory within my working directory.

```
{
    "name": "Chat",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Real Time Chat",
    "dependencies": {
         "socket.io": "latest",
        "express": "latest",
        "jade": "latest"
    },
    "author": "@pattmorter"
}
```

Good so far right?

Then I created the `server.js` file and the `script.js` file. Next I created the `home.jade` file for the UI.

```
doctype 5
html
    head
        title Chatter
        script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js')
        script(src='socket.io/socket.io.js')
        script(src='script.js')
    body
        //- some other formatting stuff that works correctly
```

When i start up my server and go to 127.0.0.1:3000, the page shows up but in the error console it says that `GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)` error.

I thought I referenced the file correctly but I guess not :( My thought process was that since the `server.js` file was rendering the `home.jade` file that I would only have to do `script(src='socket.io/socket.io.js')` within the jade file.

Any hint in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT 1** 
Here is my `server.js` snippet

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var jade = require('jade');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set("view options", { layout: false });
app.configure(function() {
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('home.jade');
});
app.listen(3000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('setPseudo', function (data) {
        socket.set('pseudo', data);
    });
    socket.on('message', function (message) {
        socket.get('pseudo', function (error, name) {
            var data = { 'message' : message, pseudo : name };
            socket.broadcast.emit('message', data);
            console.log("user " + name + " send this : " + message);
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: try adding a `/`: `/socket.io/socket.io.js`

Comment: Sounds like your `server.js` doesn't initialize `socket.io` properly. Can you post some code?

Comment: @BrianGlaz the `/` didn't help.

Comment: @Tom if you set up `socket.io` properly you don't need to have the `socket.io.js` file anywhere in a directory served by `express.static`; the `socket.io` module *does* in fact handle requests for it itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `socket.io` initialization is incorrect.

Instead of this (which actually gives me a warning):

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
...
app.listen(3000);
```

Use this:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(3000));

// or a bit more elaborate:
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io     = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

The difference is that the `.listen()` method of `socket.io` takes a [`http.Server`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) instance as argument, which is what Express' `.listen()` method happens to return.

`app` itself is an Express instance, which is something else.

Comment: That did it. Could you explain the reasoning why to use `.listen(app.listen(3000))`.

Answer (score 1):

Post your `server.js` snippet, as that is where you problem most likely is. You need to follow the examples on http://socket.io carefully to make sure socket.io is wired up to properly respond with the socket.io client javascript code when the browser requests `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to *robertklep* answer, please have a look at [Socket.IO compatibility](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x#socketio-compatibility) section in express wiki pages.

It explains about `express` `3.x` changes which *breaks* `express` `2.x` and `socket.io` examples. That's why solution proposed by *robertklep* is necessary to have `socket.io` working with the latest version of `express` server.